# How can I group elements of a List based on a conditions?

Tags: scala, list

I want to group the elements in a specific range.

For example, I have a list as follows:

```
val a = List((1.5, 2), (2.7, 5), (4.0,1), (5.25, 2), (7.80, 4), (11.41,10), (13.10, 5))
```

And I want to group all (x, y) sharing x within a given range.

For instance using ranges 1-5, 5-10, 10-15.

In order to get this output:

```
((0-5)->((1.5, 2), (2.7, 5), (4.0,1)),(5-10)->((5.25, 2), (7.80, 4)),(10-15)->((11.41,10), (13.10, 5)))
```

Comment: So you're not ready to deal with this kind of problem, don't be too quick in work

Comment: [I downvoted because it appears that no attempt was made. We all have jobs to do. It may be homework, or for assigned work at our job. No matter what, it’s our responsibility to get it done. Even when it seems like our task is too hard or we don’t know where to start, it is always worth the effort to at least try.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad, as I can't tell what specific programming problem you are having trouble with. Please share what code you have so far so we can help you diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to group tuples based on `x` (as an `Int`) divided by `5`:

```
7.0.toInt / 5 // 1
```

using `groupBy`:

```
val list = List((1.5, 2), (2.7, 5), (4.0,1), (5.25, 2), (7.80, 4), (11.41,10), (13.10, 5))

list
  .groupBy { case (x, y) => x.toInt / 5 }
  .map { case (d, values) => (Seq((d * 5), (d + 1) * 5).mkString("-"), values) }
```

which gives:

```
Map(10-15 -> List((11.41,10), (13.1,5)), 5-10 -> List((5.25,2), (7.8,4)), 0-5 -> List((1.5,2), (2.7,5), (4.0,1)))
```